# Como Referenciar uma DLL usando o <DllImport> e uma variável no caminho?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estou com um problema no momento de referencia uma dll usando o  `<DllImport>`, pois no lugar onde coloco o caminho da dll  `<DllImport("C:\MinhaDll.dll")>`, eu gostaria de usar uma variável, e não é possível, retorna o seguinte erro:

> "Erro 11  Expressão constante é necessária."

A variável que quero usar irá conter o caminho da dll, então qual o outro método que posso usar para referenciar uma dll de um caminho especifico criado pelo próprio usuário, já que preciso de um caminho fixo para usar o DllImport?

Comment: Se os caminhos *absolutos* da DLL forem diferentes, mas os caminhos *relativos* forem iguais, podes usar uma expressao constante.

Comment: Será caminhos diferentes, pode ser que em um micro a dll fique no C:, em outro fique na pasta system32 ou windows. Por isso preciso referenciar em um variável, ouu...?

Comment: E o nome da dll? É constante?

Comment: Não, nem o nome e nem o caminho, apenas as funções.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isto não seja possível fazer.

Entretanto, você pode adicionar um diretório para o caminho de pesquisa de DLLs do processo usando a [função `AddDllDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513(v=vs.85).aspx), porém como está é uma API recente, se você estiver usando uma versão inferior ao Windows *8*, será necessário instalar um [*patch*](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=217865).

A assinatura da função é:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
'

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
 Public Function AddDllDirectory(NewDirectory As String) As Integer
 End Function
```

Se você quiser modificar o caminho padrão de busca, use a [função `SetDllDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203.aspx).

Um artigo que pode ser útil ler é [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx) que menciona:

> Antes de o sistema procura uma DLL, ele verifica o seguinte:
>
> - Se uma *DLL* com o mesmo nome do módulo já está carregado na memória, o sistema usa o *DLL* carregada, não importa qual diretório
>     que se encontra. O sistema não procura a DLL.
> - Se a *DLL* está na [*lista de DLLs conhecidas*](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/2007.09.windowsconfidential.aspx) para a versão do Windows no qual o aplicativo é executado, o sistema utiliza a sua
>     cópia da *DLL* conhecida (e *DLLs* dependentes da DLL conhecida, se
>     houver).  O sistema não procura a *DLL*.
>
> Para obter uma *lista de DLLs
>   conhecidas* no sistema atual, consulte a seguinte chave do registro:
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` ⇢ `SYSTEM` ⇢ `CurrentControlSet` ⇢ `Control` ⇢ `Session`
>   `Manager` ⇢ `KnownDLLs`.

Num trecho mais abaixo ainda é mencionado o valor `SafeDllSearchMode` que fica guardado no registro.

> Se `SafeDllSearchMode` estiver habilitado <sup>no WinXP ele é desabilitado
>   por padrão</sup>, a ordem de pesquisa é a seguinte:
>
> 1. O diretório do qual o aplicativo foi carregado.
> 2. O diretório do sistema. Use a [função `GetSystemDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724373.aspx) para obter o caminho desse diretório.
> 3. O diretório do sistema de *16* bits. Não há nenhuma função que obtém o caminho deste diretório, mas ele é pesquisado.
> 4. O diretório do Windows. Use a [função `GetWindowsDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454.aspx) para obter o caminho desse diretório.
> 5. O diretório atual.
> 6. Os diretórios listados na variável de ambiente `PATH`. 
>      **Note** que isso não inclui o caminho por aplicativo especificado pela chave de registo `App Paths`.

Comment: Não sei se é uma opção para você, mas veja também: [*Run-Time Dynamic Linking*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685090(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Muito interessante, no caso essa função serve apenas eu adicionar a dll que quero em uma lista de dlls, e depois quando eu rodar a função de minha dll ela irá buscar todas dll que estão nessa lista e verificar a dll que contem a função que estou chamando, certo?
Ta, mas no caminho de minha função eu devo colocar o que? digo no dllImport de minha função. Pois não entendi essa parte, ou nao devo usar mais o dllImport para minha função ?

Comment: @FelipeWalleg Correto. No `DLLImport` você referencia a tua DLL normalmente, por exemplo: `<DllImport("MinhaDll.dll")>`, *sem o path*.